# Getting 'Query Interrupted' error in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Using MySQL Workbench, I have created a schema called 'ijdb' within which is the table 'joke'. This table has just 3 fields - `id` `joketext` and `jokedate`

When I type the following, I get 'query interrupted' on the bottom left.

```
CREATE USER 'ijdbuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `ijdb`.* TO 'ijdbuser'@'%';
```

why is this happening and what can I do to resolve this issue?

any help will be deeply appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [semi-related]:  '%' does not include 'localhost'.